# Sum of multiple selected checkboxes in JAVA

Tags: java, database, eclipse, checkbox

If I use the "+ " sign it will just concatenate the values, but I need to find the mathematical values. I need to insert the quantity of a product. How to find the sum when multiple checkboxes are selected? 
I have tried this which concatenates.. Also the values need to go into the database, it is working with the concatenated values..

```
                 if(chckbx1.isSelected()){
                    qty= chckbx1.getText();
                    chckbx1.setSelected(true);
             }

             if(chckbx1.isSelected() && chckbx5.isSelected()){
                    qty= chckbx1.getText() + chckbx5.getText();
                    chckbx5.setSelected(true);
                    chckbx1.setSelected(true);
             }
```

Comment: You can use `Integer.parseInt(chckbx1.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(chckbx5.getText());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Using the + operator on Strings concatenates them.

So, you need to convert the Strings to numbers.
Depending upon what type of numbers the Strings contain (real or integer), you may parse them to numbers in one of the following ways:

- `qty= ""+ ( Integer.parseInt(chckbx1.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(chckbx5.getText()) );`
- `qty= ""+ ( Double.parseDouble(chckbx1.getText()) + Double.parseDouble(chckbx5.getText()) );`

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse it to Double using Double.parseDouble()

```
qty= (Double.parseDouble(chckbx1.getText()) + Double.parseDouble(chckbx5.getText())) + "";
```

Comment: It's not a cast. It's a static function call.

Answer (score 0):

You may parse it to Integer using Integer.parseInt()

```
qty= (Integer.parseInt(chckbx1.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(chckbx5.getText())) + "";
```